# Check a absolute path string by regular expression

Tags: regex

I want to check a absolute path string but there are some limitation.

1. the path string cannot include "_nulog/".
2. the path string can include "/iudlog_".
3. if path string is '/iulog_nulog/', it has to pass the checking.

How can I do it by regular expression?

Its a java program.

Example:
Valid:

```
/home/ubn/LC4CBAYH36/Log_LC4CBAYH36_88267/Check/iudlog_LC4CBAYH36/log_20150104.txt
```

Invalid:

```
/home/ubn/LC4CBAYH36/Log_LC4CBAYH36_88267/Check/xc0_nulog/mobilelog/APLog_2015/main_log.4
```

Comment: post some valid and invalid examples..

Comment: This validation will be done (and maintained) *way* simpler by using 3 `if` conditions and `substring`

Comment: And what language are you using?

Comment: What if it includes none of your example strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use negative lookahead based regex like below.

```
^(?:(?!_nulog\/).)*\/iudlog_(?:nulog\/)?(?:(?!_nulog\/).)*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oT5tO2/1)